# Physical security item with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fido-u2f

The escenario: a user attach an USB pen drive or somerhing else and a webapp allows the user to Work withe the tabs. If that object is detached then the webapp will deny any operation

I've seen FIDO U2F but it doesnt reslly Work because the user must click the key to send the auth Code to Chrome. If it allowed the webapp to actively poll the usb for the key could be a good solución, but, as I said, u2f only allows the key to send the key if the user press a button.

Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: No there isn't. A webpage can't access a usb drive and so is unaware of its existance

Comment: @baao That's not totally true: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb and also the solución I thought first, u2f, is also supported by Chrome. The thing is that I need to know when thr ítem is insertes snd when is removed si the webspp csn lovk itself